# how to use --without-sqlite3 at compile time in php?

Tags: php, sqlite

I was reading [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.installation.php) about how to disable the SQLite3 extension in PHP:

> The SQLite3 extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0. It's possible to **disable it by using --without-sqlite3 at compile time**.

but i didn't realize how to use --without-sqlite3 ?

Answer (score 1):

"Compile time" refers to when someones takes the PHP source code, and compiles it into binary files. Once PHP is installed from those binaries, there is no way to disable an extension that was included in the PHP binary. (You can disable extensions that are compiled into separate binaries, but that is not the case for the SQLite3 extension for PHP. So in order to disable SQLite3 in your PHP, you'd need to obtain the source code of PHP, and compile it manually; it's not an easy task, if you've never compiled something, but I'm sure there are walkthroughs you can find online, if you really need.

Comment: so if I want to make it completely plain, in order to disable the SQLite3 extension, this piece of code ("--without-sqlite3") should be included in PHP source code before it's compiled?

Comment: `--without-sqlite3` should be included in one of the commands used to compile PHP: `./configure --without-sqlite3`

Comment: I also had to use --without-pdo-sqlite since I am using PDO.

Comment: --disable-pdo could also be used; you'll need to either used it or --without-pdo-sqlite